# Angular js ng-model not accessible for textbox control in template directive on master page asp.net

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, master-pages

i am not able to access Model for textbox, please find code below.

HTML Tag, which i am using

```
<span ng-click="LoadFieldData()">{{name.An}}</span><input type="text" 
style="width:515px;" ng-value="{{name.An}}" ng-model="name.An" 
id="topmost[0]" /></div>
```

Also,Please find the directive which i use.

```
angularform.directive("formChange",function($compile){
 return{
 restrict:"EA",
 terminal:true,
 priority:1000,
 scope:{},
 transclude:true,
 templateUrl:"../../app/Pages/dpang.html",
 css:"../../Common/Styles/style.css"
}
})
```

Also the controller function is

```
$scope.LoadFieldData = function () {
debugger;
alert('function called.')
$scope.name.An = 'An is my name';
}
```

I am calling the directive like this in a div on master page.master.

```
<form-change/>
```

but when i am trying to access the variable {{name.An}}, only {{name.an}} is displayed on the html  screen, instead of the value of variable "An is my name".
Can anybody please help.

Comment: Your directive must be camel case so if you have form-change it must be formChange in angularform.directive("formchange".

Comment: Thanks for answering.done that,it was a typo error.
Now, trying to load the controls using iframe, rather than directive, although i can call the functions in controller suing $parent.Functionname(), but, i am not able to set the model of textbox control in this html template.
Can you please Help.

Comment: Can you recreate your issue on pluner or codepen. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/A7BbpkVlgc3ACXm1Iac7?p=preview
This is the one using iframe, where model  is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work with iFrame like you are trying in the plnkr.
You should use the directive tag like this:

```
<teen-internal></teen-internal>
```

Also in your directive you dont need the empty scope:

```
myApp.directive('teenInternal', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    templateUrl: 'teen-external.html'

  };
});
```

This is should work. [Plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/GDohlFJDpFA6IVuEGnMh?p=preview&preview)

Cheers,